# OctoberCMS DynamicPDF dynamic Header Content Text

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-widgets

I am using OctoberCMS [DynamicPDF](https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-dynamicpdf) Plugin which is working absolutely fine as per my requirement.

Howerver, I have dynamic PDF header text content and I am trying to Overwrite my Header Content but its not working. Here is what I have tried so far.

**Template file**

```
{% set headerTExt = 'asdf' %}
```

**Layout file**

```
 <html>
        <head>
            <style type="text/css" media="screen">
                {{ css|raw }}
            </style>
            <title>Regency Brochure</title>
        </head>

        <div id="header">
             <div style="display: inline-block; position: absolute; left: 2.5%; top: 12px;">
                <img src="{{  logo }}" style="width: 60px; height:auto; margin-top:5px;"/> 
             </div>
             <div style="text-align: right; font-size: 20px; color: #b49132; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: 'Montserrat-Bold'; position: absolute; right: 3.5%; top: 25px;">
{{ headerTExt }}
</div>
          </div>
          <div id="footer">
             <div class="footerText">www.regencycorporate.com.au</div>
          </div>




            {{ content_html|raw }}

    </html>
```

**Layout File CSS**

```
@page { margin:25mm 0px 8mm 0px;}
         header { position: fixed; left: 0px; top:-25mm; right: 0px; height: 22mm;   background-color: #fff;   border-bottom: solid 1px #d8d8d8;}
         footer { position: fixed; left: 0px; bottom:-8mm; right: 0px;    background-color: #b49132; height: 11mm; }
         footer .footerText { font-size: 14px; text-align: center; color: white;    font-family: 'Montserrat-Medium'; font-weight:400; padding-top:8px; }
         content{
         height:645px;
         padding:0px 30px;
         }
```

As you can see, I am trying to put dynamic header text by using `{{ headerTExt }}` by setting it inside my Template file with variable `{% set headerTExt = 'asdf' %}` but its not working. If I put static text, its working but dynamic not working.

Can someone guide me how can I make it work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `{% placeholder %}`: https://octobercms.com/docs/markup/tag-placeholder

Template File:

```
{% put headerText %}Test{% endput %}
```

Layout File:

```
<html>
    <head>
        // etc
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="header">
            {% placeholder 'headerText' %}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```